# Parsing HTML with Python with no regard for correct tag hierarchy

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing, lxml

I would like to parse a document that is syntactically a html document (using tags with attributes etc), but structurally doesn't follow the rules (e.g. there could be a `<html>` tag inside a `<div>` tag inside a `<body>` tag). I also do not want the additional strictness of XML. Unfortunately, lxml only offers `document_fromstring()`, which requires a html root element, as well as `fragment_fromstring()`, which in turn does not allow there to be any `html` or `body` tags in unusual places.

How do I parse a document with no "fixing" of incorrect structure?

Comment: Have you tried a plain XML parser?

Comment: you could try beautifulsoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup should do this fine.

it would be a case of:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

then you'd search "soup" for whatever you're looking for.